# Why is my Item Level color different from my friend's?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My current Item Level is 854 in World of Warcraft. My friend's Item Level is 860. However, mine is purple and his is light blue. I would think that his would also be purple for perhaps having all epic level gear, like I do.

Any reason for the color difference?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you get the "Brokenly Superior" achievement, your item level turns blue. ([source](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20749144924#post-7))

[image: Brokenly Superior Achievement Image]